# Electron JS: Application not running after packaging using electron-packager (VCRUNTIME140.dll MSVCP140.dll)

Tags: node.js, electron

I have packaged my application for distribution on windows x64 using the given below command

```
electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=x64
```

It has packaged the application but when I am running the packaged app it is giving below prompts

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug in `electron 1.1.0`

Hope they will resolve it asap.

**Workaround**

1. Go to this link [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
2. Download it and install it (x86/x64) accordingly
3. Go to c:\windows\system32
4. Find `VCRUNTIME140.dll MSVCP140.dll` and paste in the root of your distribution app

Now your applicaiton will run.